# how to implement Rabbitmq high availability without using DRBD?

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability

I want to implement High availability for Rabbitmq server.i have read the Rabbitmq provide document,on document is use DRBD,i don't wants to use DRBD for share storage,from my side i have did clustering with two node and prepare mirror queue.
rest needs to be implemented high availability help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HA documentation can be found on the RabbitMQ site at
http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

with the main set up being described in
http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

This doesn't involve DRBD and is simply a guide on how to mirror queues across multiple servers.

I have implemented a HA rabbit cluster based on the instructions in the above so I can attest to their clarity.
If you have any specific questions regarding HA setup that isn't clear from the above then I'm happy to answer them.

Comment: Thanks. i have posted the same question on Rabbitmq forum http://old.nabble.com/can-we-implement-high-availability-without-using-DRBD--tt33862277.html#a33862277, he told me that cluster+mirror queue completes the Rabbitmq HA,also he told me to use fail over mechanism to switch node when nodes are down,but this does not solve my problem.i want implement both node failure and service failure(rabbitmq -server).if u have any idea how can i do that then please help.

Comment: also if u have any documentation regarding implementation please share with me if possible.

Comment: Node or service failure can be detected by a load-balancing proxy such as HAProxy and traffic routed accordingly. In normal operation the proxy would typically round-robin connections to the servers and, in the event of a failure, only connect clients to the one(s) that are still up. Is this what you were after? Check out http://www.joshdevins.net/2010/04/16/rabbitmq-ha-testing-with-haproxy/ for some info on this.

Comment: i have explain my problem on following post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652569/haproxy-does-not-work-with-rabbitmq .what i think that virtual ip work with only node1 not with node2.